# The ListBox Click event is lost when focus is set to a TabControl

Tags: vb.net, listbox, selectedvalue

I am working with a Visual Basic.NET project in Visual Studio 2017 (.NET Framework 4.6.1)

I am using a Listbox which is associated with a BindingSource.

The Listbox is contained within one pane of a SplitterControl.

I also have a TabControl is located within the other pane of the SplitterControl.  This control contains child data associated with the items in the ListBox and is refreshed when the ListBox is clicked and an item is subsequently selected in the ListBox.  The Click event refreshes a Treeview, which then populates the TabControl with data if/when (1) a tree node is clicked and (2) appropriate data is retrieved for that node.

The Listbox Click event works fine while clicking different items consecutively within the Listbox only.

However, once the mouse clicks in the TabControl (in the other pane of the SplitterControl), then once the initial Listbox is clicked, the Click event doesn’t fire.

I have researched this issue (on StackOverFlow as well as other forums) and suggestions have basically revolved around the idea that the Click event could be forced by calling the routine set up as the Click event handler (e.g., myListBox_Click).

I have tried this, but the problem is that I am losing the current SelectedIndex / SelectedValue.

To illustrate by reproducing the issue within the app where I am encountering the problem:

The app in question (note the Listbox highlighted by the red arrow - Screenshot 1):

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsVX2.png)

Upon startup of the app, the Listbox behaves as it should, if the user clicks nowhere else, only selecting various items within the Listbox.  The TabControl (initial tab shown is always the Profile tab) is refreshed accordingly.

However, if at any point, the mouse is clicked in the TabControl (e.g., to select another tab, note Screenshot 2)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTMID.png)

Now, when the user clicks on another item in the Listbox, the wrong item is selected (shown in Screenshot 3):

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzW6W.png)

The Click event is now being forced via a call to MyListBox_Click within the TabControl_Leave event; my thinking was that this was the appropriate place to put the subroutine call.  My reasoning was that when the Listbox was clicked in this scenario, the first event to fire (as far as I could tell) was the TabControl_Leave event.

Not surprisingly, if the same item in the Listbox (in this example scenario, Allegheny) is subsequently clicked, than the result is what should have happened on the previous click (that the SelectedValue is correct, as seen in Screenshot 4):

[Screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9c7Z.png)

Of course, this is correct, since the last click occurred while the Listbox was already the active control.

I have tried several approaches such as (1) using a global variable to store the current index/value and retrieving it, and (2) using the Tag property of the TabControl to store and retrieve the same value.  This has either worked inconsistently or not at all because of the order in which the control events fire.

Hopefully, I've been clear enough on the nature of my problem/issue.

Anyone have any ideas on what my next approach could be?  Any ideas/insights/suggestions will, of course, be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Chris Fleetwood

Software Developer

North Carolina Partnership for Children (SmartStart)

Comment: I can't answer why the issue you're experiencing occurs, but if you're only reacting to an item being clicked (i.e. selected) I think it'd be better to use the [`SelectedIndexChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged) as it occurs whenever an item is selected/deselected (either by the keyboard, mouse or programmatically). Plus it always occurs _after_ the item has been selected.

Comment: I used SelectedIndexChanged event instead.  However, I'm still seeing the issue. Apparently, the TabControl causes events outside that control to be lost (as evidenced by the fact that the TabControl Leave event does fire and the Listbox's SelectedIndexChanged event does not automatically fire). Forcing the Listbox Click, SelectionIndexChanged (or any other event for that matter) doesn't work since (by definition of the issue) I'm unable to capture the currently selected index for the Listbox.  Therein lies my problem.

Comment: I had a "Eureka!" moment and decided to implement the MouseEnter event on the ListBox control to immediately set focus to the Listbox.  This forced the Tabcontrol_Leave event to fire BEFORE I clicked on the Listbox.   Solved my problem. :)

Comment: Sorry for not seeing your reply earlier. I never really managed to reproduce the problem. Glad to hear you got it working, though!